# Mobile Safari (iOS 7) ignoring overflow values

Tags: html, ios, css, iphone, overflow

I have followed all questions on here regarding this problem but I'm still stuck.

I have a web page with a lot of `absolute` `position`ed elements on the page, and I want `overflow-x: hidden` because I have a slideout mobile menu. (If you tap the menu icon, then slide your finger left, the menu goes away but a large remaining white space stays because it's scrolling to the left). What I have tried:

```
html {
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}

body {
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}

/* I know this is repetitive, but the above two aren't working, so I'm trying this as well */

html, body {
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}

html body {
    overflow-x: hidden !important;
}
```

I have also tried using `overflow-y` in case it's an odd orientation issue, but that still doesn't work (in fact, it *still* also scrolls down/up). I have also tried `overflow: hidden !important; overflow-y: auto;` but again, doesn't work. It's as if it's completely ignoring the `overflow` rule. I know the stylesheet is fine because it's reading other rules from that stylesheet. Any ideas? If you want to check it out: http://www.lampsidewebdesign.com/

Comment: @florianbussmann and this won't remove up/down scrolling functionality?

Comment: @florianbussmann it doesn't work either way. :(